# Exact Differential Equation [ 1-Parameter Family of Solutions]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Exact Differential equation $3xy + y^2 + (x^2 +xy)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ **given** the integrating factor $u(x,y) = 1/xy(2x+y)$.

How do I evaluate the integral :

[image]

I tried different types of factoring, and u subs, but nothing seems to work out.

Similarly,

[image]

Comment: In the question is says: using the integrating factor u(x,y)= 1/xy(2x+y)

Comment: Could you show a bit more of the steps required to get that answer?

Comment: Here is some of the work I have done: I separated the integral to int[3xy/xy(2x+y) + y^2/xy(2x+y)] , for the first integral I get 6ln(2x+y) and I don't know how to do the second integral. I also don't see how you got (1/2)ln(2x+y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note
\begin{align*}
\int{\dfrac{3xy+y^2}{xy(2x+y)}\mathrm dx}&=\int\dfrac{3x+y}{x(2x+y)}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int{\dfrac{x+2x+y}{x(2x+y)}\mathrm dx}\\
&=\int{\dfrac{x}{x(2x+y)}\mathrm dx}+\int{\dfrac{2x+y}{x(2x+y)}\mathrm dx} \\
&=\int{\dfrac{1}{2x+y}\mathrm d x}+\int{\dfrac{1}{x}\mathrm d x}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln |2x+y|+\ln |x|+ k(y)
\end{align*}
where $k$ is a function of $y$.